# AADSTS70001 with personal and work account

Tags: azure, active-directory

I have set up my web application to authenticate using Azure Active Directory using OpenId. When I click on my login page to Login with OpenId it sends the following

https://login.microsoftonline.com/4ff03073-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx4ccefa6f/oauth2/authorize?client_id=173c0fb9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxbe37085a&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%blahblahblah

and I get the following error:

```
Additional technical information: 
Correlation ID: 8d7d2d50-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxbdcf8138 
Timestamp: 2015-10-13 11:43:50Z 
AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '173c0fb9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxbe37085a' was not found in the directory 4ff03073-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx4ccefa6f.
```

The application identifier is correct but the directory is pointing to my Office 365 work account directory but the Azure application is set up under my Personal account that unfortunately has the same email address. 
How do I tell my program to send the **GUID** for my personal directory not the work account directory?

Thanks...
Terry

Comment: `4ff03073-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx4ccefa6f` - Is this the GUID of your personal directory or Office365 directory?

Comment: I am now able to get it to go to the correct directory by specifying the specific xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com domain rather than the company domain in the authority setting for the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.                                                         The problem now though is that I am getting the more common error System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) 
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.<AuthenticateAsync>d__8.MoveNext()